# Optional capture group till end of line

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following strings

I have the following regex

```
^\/\/\s(prevent\s?eval\s|eval\s?prevent)\s?([^\n]*)$
```

What I am trying to do is match the following:

```
// preventeval
hello world
```

[preventEval]

```
// preventeval meow
hello world
```

[preventEval, meow]

https://regexr.com/529p7

Answer (score 1):

`\s` matches any whitespace character, and a newline character *is* a whitespace character, so it gets matched by it (and then the whole next line is matched by `([^\n]*)`).

Optionally match a plain space instead (and remove the `\s` from the end of `prevent\s?eval\s` in the first alternation).

You can also use `.*` instead of `[^\n]*`, you probably wouldn't want to match a linefeed character anyway:

```
^\/\/\s(prevent\s?eval|eval\s?prevent) ?(.*)$
```

It sounds likely that you don't want *any* of the `\s`s to match newlines in which case, replace them all with plain spaces:

```
^\/\/ (prevent ?eval|eval ?prevent) ?(.*)$
```